# Presentation of the symmetric group of 5 symbols.

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-presentation

I am trying to write the presentation of the symmetric group $S_{5}$. We know that $S_{5}$ is generated by $a=(1,2)$ and $b=(1,2,3,4,5)$. Using this I am trying to write presentation of $S_{5}$.

My attempt is $$S_{5}= \langle a,b : a^{2}, b^{5},(ab)^{4}, (ab^{2})^{6},(ab^{3})^{6},(ab^{4})^{4} \rangle.$$

But I am confused. Is this right or not? Please give me suggestions, or write the correct short form.

Comment: please conform if you are correct....because i have to use this presentation in my work..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have written is not a presentation. In general it is not a good or efficient strategy to just write down powers of elements hoping that you will get a presentation. The best known presentation of $S_5$ is on the generators $a=(1,2)$, $b=(2,3)$, $c=(3,4)$, $d=(4,5)$:
$$\langle a,b,c,d \mid a^2,b^2,c^2,d^2,(ab)^3,(bc)^3,(cd)^3,(ac)^2,(ad)^2,(cd)^2 \rangle.$$
If you really need a presentation on the generators $a=(1,2)$, $b=(1,2,3,4,5)$, then I can easily find one on a computer:
$$\langle a,b \mid a^2,b^5,(ab)^4,(bab^{-2}ab)^2 \rangle,$$
which you could rewrite as
$$\langle a,b \mid a^2,b^5,(ab)^4,[a,b^2]^2 \rangle.$$

Comment: Thanking you and please tell me how to find in computer

Comment: @Derek, could you please provide a reference which I can use to derive the best known presentation? Thanks.